# 3d C array to Assembly

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I am rendering 10x12 pixel maps together across the video buffer

```
buffer[20][512] = malloc(10*12)
```

I have up to 512 potential 10x12 bitmaps in 20 groups. I am only using one group number: `0  buffer[group][number of 10x12 tiles]`

Hence, `buffer[0][mapindex]`

I only need to index a different map every time I call the function.
I am passing the buffer to the nasm function `tile_render(buffer,0,mapindex);`

This is where I am getting lost:

```
    lea esi,[ebp + 12]; Passing the buffer from the stack

    mov eax,[ebp + 36]   ;Location of mapindex on the stack

    I am looping through 10 x 12 trying to render the pixels

    mov dl,[4*esi + eax +8] 

    move byte [edi + ebx],dl  ;moving one byte at a time.

    //code omitted

    add ebx,320
```

However, I am not finding the correct address of the 10x12 pixels, meaning I am just getting garble on the screen.

There are of course other ways to handle this, which I can do just fine but I want to know how to work with 3-dimensional arrays in  assembly better. My experience is a newbie when it comes to this so I am hoping someone has dealt with this situation before.

Comment: Found the solution for this case:

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this case:

```
mov esi,[ebp + 12] ; buffer[20][512] = malloc(10*12)
mov edx,[esi]    ;Move to first bitmap
lea esi,[edx]    ;first bitmap address
mov eax,[ebx + 36] ;index to each map
mov ecx,120        ;120 = 12x10 size bit map
mul ecx            ;120 x map index.
mov dl. [esi + eax] ;index through to the output buffer
mov [edi + ebx],dl   ; next
.
.
.
add ebx,320
```

Comment: to put a code block just select it and press the `{}` button on the toolbar, or press Ctrl+K. On the right of the toolbar there's also a [help button](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), please spend a few minutes to know how to format your code properly